# Get the number left to to match the Multiplication of 6

Tags: twig

I have a a variable `{{ product.amount }}` and need to display the amount left of a  multiplication of 6.

So for example `{{ product.amount }}` is 20. so it has to output `4`. (for 24)

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can directly use modulo in twig template, as [documentation said](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#math) :

```
{{ 6 - product.amount % 6 }}
```

Comment: Why? He wants to output 4 on his use case!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **modulo** to calculate the rest of the division by 6 and then calculate the difference

```
select 6-(20 % 6) as Solved
```